# Cron job generates crontab.txt: not found

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, cron

Trying to figure out the reason(s) a script is not running properly in Cron.

Setup a shell to call a *.py file every minute with the following (Removed opening and closing # lines):

```
* * * * * python /root/job.sh
```

The job.sh runs a *.py file which checks an I2C temperature module and sends the results to Ubidots. It works fine manually. Tried restarting Cron (start, enable, and restart) and a few other variations such as adding username and full paths to job.sh.

The file has the following properties (also tried chmod a+x, u+x, 755, 666 and others):

-rwx--x--x    1 root     root            62 Jul 21 15:07 job.sh

Checking logread indicates that cron it running:

```
Fri Jul 21 15:38:00 2017 cron.info crond[3464]: USER root pid 3491 cmd /root/job.sh
```

Created a log file and directed output to it with the following:

```
 * * * * * python /root/job.sh >/root/test1.log 2>&1
```

Output in file contains the following:

```
-ash: crontab.txt: not found
```

But the crontab.txt is listed in /etc/crontabs as root (filename) with the job listed in it.

Any ideas on what to try next? Just don't won't to have a script running in an infinite loop after startup.

Comment: /etc/crontabS? Also, is it listed with full path?

Comment: Full path as indicated by pwd where root file is located: 
/etc/crontabs

Comment: Is job.sh written in bash or python?

Comment: Job.sh calls a python program  via `#!/usr/bin/env python
python /root/temperature-monitor/main.py`. Made it to test the cron.

Answer (score 0):

Issue caused by newline characters in crontab file. Used `crontab -e` to remove the `^M` which were preventing it from running successfully.